# Postgres is stuck when creating a database?

Tags: postgresql

I just installed Postgres on Ubuntu 20 on WSL, I've never used Postgres before. Both of the following are stuck forever:

```
CREATE DATABASE foo
WITH
OWNER = postgres      
ENCODING = 'UTF8'     
CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

And:

```
sudo -u postgres createdb foo
```

Here's the log:

```
2021-11-02 03:40:34.120 PDT [545] postgres@postgres ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2021-11-02 03:40:34.120 PDT [545] postgres@postgres STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE foo;
2021-11-02 03:40:38.313 PDT [567] ERROR:  canceling autovacuum task
2021-11-02 03:40:50.395 PDT [545] postgres@postgres ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2021-11-02 03:40:50.395 PDT [545] postgres@postgres STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE foo;
2021-11-02 03:41:18.896 PDT [551] ERROR:  canceling autovacuum task
```

Restarting Postgres or restarting the computer doesn't help and there's no locks. I also tried manually killing every lock. MySQL has been working for years.

What are some possible causes for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently caused by a change in PostgreSQL and the only workarounds appear to be recompiling it with the flag -DWAIT_USE_POLL or using an older version.

(WSL2 would work, too)

Mailing list discussion for details: https://www.spinics.net/lists/pgsql/msg209893.html

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with Ubuntu 22.04, Postgres 14, WSL 1. I was able to resolve the issue by upgrading Postgres version to 15

Directions for installing postgres 15 on ubuntu: https://www.linuxtechi.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu/